# How can I add a shortcut to the Windows Administrative Tools menu on Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016

How can I add a shortcut to the Windows Administrative Tools menu - the one off the Start menu - on Server 2016?

I have tried adding it to:

```
C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
C:\Users\<current-user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click in the folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools` and then create a "New" > "Shortcut".

In the next window just paste this `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools` and click OK.

Then you should have a shortcut.